# Assign Key to Existing Array

Tags: php, json

Assuming i have a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) array like this example below :

```
[{"type":"food","alias":"meal"}]
```

And i want to assign this whole array to a particular key called "Dish" for example.

How can i archive this ?

Expected output should be something like :

```
"Dish":[{"type":"food","alias":"meal"}]
```

I know how to create new key value pairs but never thought of assigning a key until now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$json = '[{"type":"food","alias":"meal"}]';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = array('Dish' => $data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this..

```
<?php
$json = '[{"type":"food","alias":"meal"}]';
$arr = array('dish'=>json_decode($json,true));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/139188)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode(array('Dish' => json_decode($json, true)));
//{"Dish":[{"type":"food","alias":"meal"}]}
```